# Javascript: how to prevent duplicate key-value pairs from getting added into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I am trying to create a shopping cart using vanilla javascript and OOJS concepts.

```js
let inventory = [
    { item: "apples", price: 19, qty: 50 },
    { item: "oranges", price: 20, qty: 40 },
    { item: "pineapples", price: 40, qty: 60 },
    { item: "lemons", price: 10.12, qty: 100 }
  ];
  
  function MyBasket(inventory) {
    this.totalItems = [];
  }
  
  MyBasket.prototype.addItems = function(item, price, qty) {
    this.totalItems.push({ item: item, price: price, qty: qty });
  };

  MyBasket.prototype.removeItems = function(item, price, qty) {
    let a =inventory.filter(e=>e.item==item);
    inventory.splice(inventory.indexOf(a),1);
    console.log(inventory)
  };

  MyBasket.prototype.updateInventory = function() {
    cart.totalItems.forEach(i => {
      const item = inventory.find(o => o.item === i.item);
      if (item) item.qty -= i.qty;
    });
  }
  
  MyBasket.prototype.cartItems = function() {
    return this.totalItems;
  };
  
  MyBasket.prototype.totalAmount = function() {
    return this.totalItems.reduce((acc, item) => {
      return acc + item.price * item.qty;
    }, 0);
  };
  
  var cart = new MyBasket();
  
  cart.addItems("apples", 19, 2);
  cart.addItems("oranges", 20, 3);
  cart.addItems("lemons", 5, 4);
  cart.updateInventory();
  console.log("updated inventory", inventory);

  cart.removeItems('lemons',10.12,100);
  console.log("cart items", cart.cartItems());

  console.log("total Amount", cart.totalAmount());

  cart.updateInventory();
  console.log("updated inventory", inventory);
```

Above is the js code for the app. Later I will create the UI for it and use an `eventListener` that will call my parent Class MyBasket().

I have an `updateInventory()` which basically compares the cartItems to the inventory and then subtracts the corresponding quantity of that item from the inventory. Whenever there is any change in the inventory, this function should check and give the updated inventory. For example, after adding items to the cart or after removing items from the cart.

**Problem is with the `updateInventory()`:** when I run `updateInventory()` after adding items, it contains duplicated values. It should only contain the updated list.

Now, if I remove some items the cart, the inventory should be updated. now when I run the `updateInventory()`, it again subtracts the quantity. this results in wrong inventory information.

Comment: Either run a search before adding to the array or keep a map of all items and look them up before inserting.

Comment: @VLAZ could you please put that in code, so that I can understand better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `array` make it a `set`. While using `reduce` and other array functions you can convert the `set` to `array` again using

```
Array.from()
```

```js
let inventory = [
    { item: "apples", price: 19, qty: 50 },
    { item: "oranges", price: 20, qty: 40 },
    { item: "pineapples", price: 40, qty: 60 },
    { item: "lemons", price: 10.12, qty: 100 }
  ];
  
  function MyBasket(inventory) {
    this.totalItems = new Set();
  }
  
  MyBasket.prototype.addItems = function(item, price, qty) {
    this.totalItems.add({ item: item, price: price, qty: qty });
  };

  MyBasket.prototype.removeItems = function(item, price, qty) {
    let a =inventory.filter(e=>e.item==item);
    inventory.splice(inventory.indexOf(a),1);
    console.log(inventory)
  };

  MyBasket.prototype.updateInventory = function() {
  this.totalItems=Array.from(cart.totalItems);
    cart.totalItems.forEach(i => {
      const item = inventory.find(o => o.item === i.item);
      if (item) item.qty -= i.qty;
    });
  }
  
  MyBasket.prototype.cartItems = function() {
    return this.totalItems;
  };
  
  MyBasket.prototype.totalAmount = function() {
   this.totalItems=Array.from(cart.totalItems);
    return this.totalItems.reduce((acc, item) => {
      return acc + item.price * item.qty;
    }, 0);
  };
  
  var cart = new MyBasket();
  
  cart.addItems("apples", 19, 2);
  cart.addItems("oranges", 20, 3);
  cart.addItems("lemons", 5, 4);
  cart.updateInventory();
  console.log("updated inventory", inventory);

  cart.removeItems('lemons',10.12,100);
  console.log("cart items", cart.cartItems());

  console.log("total Amount", cart.totalAmount());

  cart.updateInventory();
  console.log("updated inventory", inventory);
```

Comment: Or...you can use a Map - a datastructure *designed* to keep items which you can lookup by key. Why use a set if you're just going to parse it to and from arrays with every interaction?

Comment: Also, looking at this - how does `addItems` ensure uniqueness *at all* - in a set, it's the reference to the object that has to be unique when inserting so `basket.addItems("oranges", 20, 10)` called *twice* will add two distinct entries because `{ item: "oranges", price: 20, qty: 10 } !== { item: "oranges", price: 20, qty: 10 }`

Comment: even if you use map, OP is using reduce and filter on it, so both ways you need to convert it to array as it is better to change the code for one data structure change

Comment: actually, a set is totally adapted `The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.` cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: @h1b9b yes object ***references*** is the key here. Try this `set = new Set();  set.add({name: "Bob"}); set.add({name: "Bob"});` and you'd get two entries in the set.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh yes that true, my bad sry

Comment: @ellipsis I think there is more to a basket than what the backing datastructure is. A bigger problem I see is that the interface is bad - it's passing arbitrary things to the basket to store. It should be accepting only cart items. In general, you shouldn't be able to call `basket.add("oranges", 20, 10)` and `basket.add("oranges", 30, 10)` or ``basket.add("orange", 20, 10)` - it doesn't make sense to have both 20 "orange" and 20 "orange**s**" in the cart, nor does it make sense to have "oranges" costing 20 and "oranges" costing 30 in the cart at the same time.

Comment: And yes, I am aware you can go to the shop and get two different kinds of oranges but you don't identify them by the basic description. There is more to identifying items than by name - two different items named "oranges" mean that a lookup of "oranges" will yield the first one and won't update the second one.

Comment: @VLAZ I can only add items to my cart which exist in the inventory. Could you direct me to right way of this. thanks.